# How to include new rows and columns in a data frame (matrix) and perform a mathematical operation based on these in the dataset in R

Tags: r, dataframe, equation

I am quite new in R and I am facing problem on analysing a dataset.

I have a dataset like this. It is actually a factorial cross result (Aa, Ab, Ac, ..., Ba, Bb, Bc, etc) in biology. A, B, C, D, E, F and a, b, c, d have their own value which I wrote down below inside the code. I want to apply a formula on each and every cells in the main data set. The equation is in the code[(X-(Xi + Yj/2)/(Xi + Yj/2)*100] (I tried for only one cell as an example; and I was not getting how to perform the equation for all the dataset). Should these values be in a new row and column in the dataset? And I want to colour the new cell values after performing the equation. Let's say, according to the value (60-80], (80-100], (100-120], (120-140]. Would you mind guiding me in this regard?

```
a <- c(103, 110, 105, 108, 101, 100)
b <- c(105, 108, 121, 96, 110, 100)
c <- c(106, 110, 110, 113, 118, 107)
d <- c(103, 115, 105, 113, 98, 100)
data <- data.frame(a, b, c, d)
rownames(data) <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")
data
#>     a   b   c   d
#> A 103 105 106 103
#> B 110 108 110 115
#> C 105 121 110 105
#> D 108  96 113 113
#> E 101 110 118  98
#> F 100 100 107 100

X_i <- c("A" = 60, "B" = 57, "C" = 62, "D" = 57, "E" = 60, "F" = 57)
Y_j <- c("a" = 60, "b" = 40, "c" = 63, "d" = 45)
df <- ((data[1, 1] - ((A + a)/2))/ (A + a)/2)*100
#> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): object 'A' not found
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another solution but I believe the matrix solution proposed above is much simpler and more straightforward. Here we use `pmap` funciton of `purrr` package to iterate over 3 arguments at once in a row-wise operation. Please be noted that we created 2 other data frames out of your `X_i` and `Y_j` vectors, the same dimension as the original data frame. Then I used `pmap` function for the arithmetic operation. First I gathered all three data sets in a list and in the formula section `..1`, `..2` and `..3` each refer to the corresponding elements of each data set in the same row, since we are carrying out a row_wise operation and all three data sets are of same dimension.

```
library(purrr)

df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(X_i, nrow = length(X_i), ncol = length(Y_j)))
df2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(Y_j, nrow = length(X_i), ncol = length(Y_j), byrow = TRUE))


pmap_dfr(list(data, df1, df2), ~ (..1 - (..2 + ..3)/2) / (..2 + ..3)/2 * 100)


# A tibble: 6 x 4
      a     b     c     d
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  17.9  27.5  18.1  24.0
2  22.0  30.7  20.8  31.4
3  18.0  34.3  19    24.1
4  21.2  24.5  22.1  30.4
5  17.1  30    23.0  21.7
6  17.7  26.5  19.6  24.0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked! A made a mistake in my formula though. I made a mistake in my formula. But your solution is perfect. I intended to use the formula: result <- ((data - (Xi + Yj)/2) / ((Xi + Yj)/2))*100

Comment: It's my pleasure, let me know if there is anything I could help.

Comment: Obviously, I will. For now, it worked fantastic. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is simpler if you use matrices:

```
Xi <- matrix(X_i, nrow=length(X_i), ncol=(length(Y_j)))
Yj <- matrix(Y_j, nrow=length(X_i), ncol=(length(Y_j)), byrow=TRUE)
result <- (data - (Xi + Yj)/2) / (Xi + Yj)/2 * 100
result
#          a        b        c        d
# 1 17.91667 27.50000 18.08943 24.04762
# 2 22.00855 30.67010 20.83333 31.37255
# 3 18.03279 34.31373 19.00000 24.06542
# 4 21.15385 24.48454 22.08333 30.39216
# 5 17.08333 30.00000 22.96748 21.66667
# 6 17.73504 26.54639 19.58333 24.01961
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked! I appreciate all your cordial help. :) I made a mistake in my formula. I intended to use the formula: result <- ((data - (Xi + Yj)/2) / ((Xi + Yj)/2))*100. By the way, the solution is perfect. Thanks again. :)